# Weird Oracle Apex error, non-existent typo

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

In my Oracle SQL script I have 1 error, and that is that whenever I do this simple insert command for this table:

```
 INSERT INTO "Table1" VALUES (3, 5, 5);
```

and run the script, it shows me an error that I had a typo and wrote:

```
INSERT INTO "Table1"LUES (3, 5, 5);
```

Obviously, I go back to the code, fix the 'typo', save it and run it again, and same thing happens every single time. When I delete that line of code, the same typo happens in the next line. When I delete all the inserts for that table, the 'typo' happens in the next statement, which says that I wrote

> HelID

instead of

> HotelID

and sometimes the error changes to

```
INSERT INTO "Table1"VA (3, 5, 5);
```

and similar. I'm really confused, I tried restarting APEX and everything else I could think of.

Comment: Where does this happen? In SQL Workshop? Which Apex version is it? Did you verify that you didn't accidentally press the "Insert" key on the keyboard (and turned ON the *replace* mode)? Also, not related to your problems, consider not naming Oracle objects using mixed letter case (and - therefore - enclosing their names into double quotes).

Comment: It is in SQL Workshop -> SQL Scripts, version 19.1.0.00.15, I didn't press the insert key, I do use double quotes.

Comment: I'm on 18.2. Tried to do that, no problem. Commands I ran were `create table "Test" (ca number, cb number, cc number);` and `insert into "Test" values (1, 2, 3);`, everything went well.

Comment: I know, the same thing works for other tables but not for this part of the code.

Comment: Unfortunately, I wouldn't know what's wrong. I hope someone else will be able to assist.

Comment: Have you tried logging out and in again? Are you using a supported browser?

Comment: Yes I tried that, I'm using Chrome